# Загрузка большого дампа в MySQL

Tags: dump, sql

Попробовал скачивать `bigdump`, скрипт для загрузки большого дампа, 1ГБ, но почему-то всегда устанавливает 3 таблицы последних, вместо всех 6. С чем это может быть связано?

http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mysqldump --opt --user=user --password=password DB TABLE >file_name.sql // создать дамп таблицы одной

mysql --user=user --password=password DB < file_name.sql // залить дамп в БД
```

И ничего не нужно нигде править, все нормально зальется через командную строку.

Comment: @Shrek, я не делал дамп по одному. А делал сразу целиком. 6 таблиц.

Comment: Ну так сделай сразу всю БД в чем проблема то? убери TABLE из запроса.

Comment: @Shrek, так почему-то загружает 3 таблицы последние из 6...

Comment: Может ошибка в SQL запросе есть?

Answer (score 2):

Нужно изменить значение *max_allowed_packet* в my.cnf. При дампе больше 1GB попробуйте выставить

```
max_allowed_packet=2G
```

и после перезагрузки mysql залить дамп.

Comment: @brute, в денвере как то это сделать?

Comment: @ModaL, посмотрите (например, в доке к денверу), где у вас расположен файл my.cnf (my.ini) и исправьте значение параметра, который указал @brute. Он может быть с в директории с mysql, в директории Windows, где-нибудь в Users...

Comment: @brute, `max_allowed_packet` устанавливает максимальный размер для одного запроса, а не для всего дамп-скрипта.